# regular expressions in perl explanation

Tags: regex, perl

I need help in understanding the below regular expressions.

Can somebody please tell what this means `m/^(\d+\/\d+\/\d+\s\d+\:\d+\:\d+\.\d+)/msx`

```
foreach my $line ( @{ $self->{'stdout'} } ) {
        if ( $line =~ m/^(\d+\/\d+\/\d+\s\d+\:\d+\:\d+\.\d+)/msx ) {
            $timestamp = $1;
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried doing any searching? What part are you stuck on? Check out the docs: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ has every symbol in that regex explained. Also list apps that you can use to test your regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

This original regex

```
m/^(\d+\/\d+\/\d+\s\d+\:\d+\:\d+\.\d+)/msx
```

is a very poorly-written pattern that matches a date/time string that looks like `2014/07/31 22:53:42.123`

Since it contains no dots `.` the `/s` modifier is redundant.

The `/x` modifier allows whitespace layout to be added so we may as well do that, using a different delimiter so that slashes don't need escaping

```
m{ ^ ( \d+ / \d+ / \d+ \s \d+ : \d+ : \d+ \. \d+ ) }mx
```

So that matches

- From the beginning of any line (i.e. at the start of the string or right after a newline because the `/m` modifier is in effect)
- Capture the following
- Some digits, a slash, some more digits, another slash, some more digits
- A white space character (here I think a space was assumed)
- Some digits, a colon, some more digits, another colon, some more digits, a dot, some more digits
- Stop capturing

So, as I said, it would match (and capture)

```
2014/07/31 22:53:42.123
```

It would also match

```
0/1/2 3:4:5.6
```

I hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

This

```
if ( $line =~ m/^(\d+\/\d+\/\d+\s\d+\:\d+\:\d+\.\d+)/msx ) {
```

is quite unreadable, though the author made a start to make it readable as it has the `/x` flag (allowing whitespace, but not made use of), but it still suffers from backslashitis and doesn't limit the matches to what is really meant.

Rewriting it with different delimiters allows to get rid of some of the backslashes:

```
if ( $line =~ m{^(\d+/\d+/\d+\s\d+:\d+:\d+\.\d+)}msx ) {
```

Adding whitespace and using `[.]` instead to match a single dot and adding comments can provide a better idea of what would be matched:

```
if ( $line =~ m{^       # (start of line)
    (                   # (capture group $1)
        \d+ / \d+ / \d+ # digit(s) slash digit(s) slash digit(s)
        \s              # ANY whitespace character (space, tab, etc)
        \d+ : \d+ : \d+ # digit(s) colon digit(s) colon digit(s)
        [.] \d+         # dot digit(s)
    )                   # (end capture group $1)
}msx ) {
```

Where `digit(s)` means one ore more digits 0-9 (or any utf8 digit). So this would happily match something like "00000/0000/0000000000     0000:0000000000000000000000:000000.0000", but it seems they meant to match e.g. "0000/00/00 00:00:00.000" (a time stamp including milliseconds).

A better regex (with a lower chance of matching something it shouldn't, though it is anchored to the start of the line so no real practical difference here but as a general rule it's highly advisable to be as specific as you can) would be something like this:

```
if ( $line =~ m{^
    (
        [0-9]{4} / [0-9]{2} / [0-9]{2}
        [ ]                   # space character
        [0-9]{2} : [0-9]{2} : [0-9]{2}
        [.] [0-9]{3}
    )
}msx ) {
```

With that in hand, the regex manpage others linked already should make more sense.

Comment: I like this answer but why the switch from `\d` to `[0-9]` in your last regex?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Because `\d` can match ANY digit, including utf8 characters: `$ perl -E 'use utf8; say "matched" if "६" =~ /\d/'` prints `matched`. For e.g. form validation that can become a problem.